# How to select the correct id for the specific button pressed in dynamic table

Tags: php, jquery

I'm relatively new to jquery and cannot for the life of me get this to return the proper youtube id it just always returns the first one in the table.

php.
I load the youtube id from my database then display it in the table.

```
require_once 'library/Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
echo '<br/>';
echo '<table width="95%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0">'; 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($videoquery))
{
$vidid = ($row['id']);
$vidtitle = ($row['title']);
$vidip = ($row['ip']);
$page2 = ($row['page']);
$q = ($row['youtubeid']);

$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry($q);
$thumbnail = '<img src="' . $videoEntry->mediaGroup->thumbnail[0]->url . '" width="100" height="92"';

echo '<tr bgcolor="#333">
 <td width="100px" rowspan="2" nowrap="nowrap" style="border:2px solid #999999">'.$thumbnail.'</td>
 <td colspan="2" align="left">' .$vidtitle. '
 </td></tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#3B3B3B"><td nowrap="nowrap">
 <form method="post">
 <input name="parse" type="hidden" value="playvid" /><input name="youtubeid" id="youtubeid" type="hidden" value="'.$q.'" />;
 <input type="button" name="play" id="play" value="Play Video" />
 </form></td>
 <td align="right">
 <form method="post" action="">
 <input type="hidden" name="page2" value="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'">
 <input name="parse" type="hidden" value="deletepost2" />
 <input name="postid2" type="hidden" value="'.$vidid.'"/>';
if ($topuserid == $_GET['id']){
 echo '<input type="submit" name="deletepost2" id="deletepost2" value="Delete Video" /';>
}  
echo  '</form></td></tr>';  
}  
echo   '</table>';  
}
```

Jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#play').live('click', function() {
$('#video').empty()
var vidid = $('#youtubeid').val(); 
alert(vidid);
var playvid = '<object width="300" height="193">'+
'<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+vidid+'&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1"></param>'+
'<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>'+
'<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>'+
'<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+vidid+'&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="300" height="193"></embed>'+
'</object>';
$('#video').append(playvid);    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nathan had the right idea but had some errors in his code. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#play').live('click', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.find('#video').empty();
    var vidid = tr.find('#youtubeid').val(); 
    alert(vidid);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No problem! If you could mark my answer as accepted it would be awesome; it would help my "reputation" rating.

Comment: thanks for the follow up.  this is why formatting your code is important... :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to give your selector some context.  implementing no changes in your html you could change your js to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr')
$('#play').live('click', function() {
tr.find('#video').empty()
var vidid = tr.find('#youtubeid').val(); 
alert(vidid);
var playvid = '<object width="300" height="193">'+
'<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+vidid+'&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1"></param>'+
'<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>'+
'<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>'+
'<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+vidid+'&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="300" height="193"></embed>'+
'</object>';
tr.find('#video').append(playvid);    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response but it still doesn't seem to be assigning any value to the vidid variable :-/